# Solving a linear problem through optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I'm sorry if this is somewhat of a non-experienced/easy problem to solve. I am not even sure I'm properly defining my problem. This is fully based on measurements of a complex system (that return me complex values). My problem looks like a simple linear problem like this:

$$
Y = A\cdot X+B
$$

Where Y is a known vector of size 1xN of complex values, A is a purely diagonal matrix of size NxN with complex valued elements of the type $\exp{(j\theta_i)}, i = 1, ..., N$, X is a 1xN vector of unknown values and B is a 1xN vector of constant value $b$ which is also unknown. The goal of this is to find $min(abs(X-X_0))$ for fixed $X_0$, fixed Y and variable A.

What I struggle to do here since I haven't looked into this kind of problems in forever is how I'd implement the optimization in code (i.e: matlab, octave or python). I believe I'd also need to rewrite the $A\cdot X + B$ into something more like:

$$
A\cdot X + B = A'\cdot\begin{bmatrix}X_0\\X_1\\\vdots\\X_N\\b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But I'm not sure if this even possible.

Any help is appreciated and I'm sorry again if this is a bad question, I'll completely understand if you judge so.

Comment: This depends on what tool you are going to use. For example in YALMIP https://yalmip.github.io/ (Matlab) or CVXPY https://www.cvxpy.org/ (Python) you can write your problem almost as verbatim translation of your equations. I really recommend you try one of these, or many many other modeling tools. They do all the reformulations and call the solver for you. Otherwise you may have to fit your problem into some solver format.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the problem, calling

$$
\cases{Y=Y_r+j Y_i\\ A = \{a_{k,k}\}=\{\cos\theta_k+j\sin\theta_k\}=A_r+jA_i\\ X = X_r+jX_i\\ B=b_r+jb_i\\ X_0 = (X_0)_r+j(X_0)_i}
$$
we have

$$
\min_{X,A,B}\|X_r-(X_0)_r\|^2+\|X_i-(X_0)_i\|^2\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \cases{Y_r-A_r X_r+A_iX_i-b_r=0\\ Y_i-A_iX_r-A_rX_i-b_i=0}
$$